# write long strings to text file in python

Tags: python, file

I tried to write some long strings (whose length is about 4000000 characters such as: {}, [], 0~9, a~z) to a text file, but the new line couldn't wrap correctly. My code is as follows：

```
fp = open('output.txt', 'w')
for obj in objs:
    line = json.dumps(obj)
    fp.write(line + '\n')
fp.close()
```

There was a character: "^J" at the end of each long string rather than a new line:

[image: img01]

But if the string was short, the result was correct.

Comment: That's a line feed character. It's what `\n` would be interpreted as in most *nix systems.  Are you on WIndows, by chance? Either your python build doesn't have universal newline support or something is going wrong with it. I'm not sure why the line length matters, but try explicitly specifying that you want universal line ending conversion by opening the file with `open('output.txt', 'U')`.

Comment: Another possibility is that it's somehow a bug in your text editor that's triggered by line lengths over some threshold.  What editor are you using?

Comment: I am on Linux and  use vim as my text editor(I don't appoint any personal settings to it). I used command:`wc -l` to count the line number, the result is correct. So I tried to open `output.txt` by Sublime2 or Gedit, it's OK in these text editor.